# Android, Retrofit2, get request string

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm using Retrofit2 to get data in my Android applications. It looks like this:

```
interface ApiChatService {
    @GET("ncs-chat-web/rest/v1/message")
    suspend fun getChatMessages(@Header("Authorization") jwtToken: String, @Query("page") page: Long, @Query("count") count: Int): Response<List<ChatMessageApi>>
}
```

I call this Retrofit function this way:

```
override suspend fun getChatMessages(
    jwtToken: String,
    page: Long
): OperationResult<List<ChatMessageApi>> {
    return try {
        val response: Response<List<ChatMessageApi>> =
            apiChatService.getChatMessages(normalizeJwtToken(jwtToken), page = page, count = MESSAGE_PAGE_SIZE)
        if (response.isSuccessful) {
            OperationResult(operationResult = Result.OK, resultObject = response.body())
        } else {
            Log.d("ApiDatasourceImpl.getChatMessages", response.errorBody()?.string()?: "Empty error message")
            OperationResult(
                operationResult = Result.ERROR,
                operationInfo = response.errorBody()?.string()
            )
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.d("ApiDatasourceImpl.getChatMessages", e.localizedMessage ?: "Empty error message")
        OperationResult(operationResult = Result.ERROR, operationInfo = e.localizedMessage)
    }
}
```

In my Android code I got response code 500 with message "Internal server error"

When I call this request in Postman with such URL

https://my-server.com/ncs-chat-web/rest/v1/message?count=10&page=1

I got 200 code and expected payload.

I'm wondering is there any way to get URL which create Retrofit based on my interface function?

Comment: Have you tried you add http logging interceptor to retrofit and check if you Postman' request is identical to Android's?

Also, 500 is a backend crash, Are you able to see stacktrace of the issue from the backend?

Comment: Thank you. Could you give me example about logging interceptor? Thank you in advance

Comment: here's an example for interceptor https://medium.com/swlh/okhttp-interceptors-with-retrofit-2dcc322cc3f3. Also, I think you should put the Header annotation outside the function call, right above the Get annotation.

Comment: Thank you @aguiarroney You reference to medium article was very useful